# ¿Qué rutas serían más correctas para PUT y DELETE en API Rest?

Tags: api, web, rest, buenas-prácticas

Quería consultar una duda sobre la creación de rutas, en concreto para los casos de PUT Y DELETE.
Para comentarlo voy a utilizar la relación de ejemplo *usuarios* y sus N *direcciones-postales*

> [usuarios] 1:N [direcciones-postales]

Para los casos de GET y POST, tendría claro que sus rutas serían estas:

```
GET > usuarios/1/direcciones-postales

POST > usuarios/1/direcciones-postales {body: objeto direccionpostal}
```

Pero, en el caso de PUT/DELETE, no sabría bien que enfoque dar, ya que para mí, podrian tomar estas dos formas.

```
PUT > usuarios/1/direcciones-postales/1 {body: objetos direccionpostal}
```

ó de forma directa

```
PUT > direcciones-postales/1  {body: objeto direccionpostal}
```

En el primer caso necesitaría del identificador de usuario, algo que no tendría por qué indicar, ya que va implicito en *direcciones-postales*, por otro lado, con la segunda opción cambia el controlador raíz, y parece poco coherente que para menejar un recurso, se tenga que acceder a dos controladores distintos, en este caso: *usuario* y *direcciones-postales*

¿Qué forma sería más correcta de estas dos, o alguna otra?

Comment: esto parece mas opinion, pero personalmente creo que lo mejor es la primera opcion: `PUT > usuarios/1/direcciones-postales/1` debido a que las direcciones postales son de un usuario, no son una entidad independiente (usuarios es padre de las direcciones postales). ademas, tiene mucho sentido que requieras el identificador de un usuario, sino tu api podria dar las direcciones de cualquier usuario, sin verificar ser dicho usuario o que exista. Ademas eso te permite verificar si el usuario del que quieres saber la direccion es el propietario de dicha direccion.

Comment: es que realmente, direcciones-postales/1, sí que lo veo como una entidad independiente, es decir, ya tiene su identificador único, sabemos que si o si va a afectar a ese recurso.

Comment: entonces no cumplirias tu propia estructura de endpoints. Si te das cuenta, un user puede crear una direccion en POST usuarios/1/direcciones-postales. Si pudieras editar desde /direcciones-postales, entonces deberias tambien poder crear desde /direcciones-postales.. por que esta bajo la jerarquia de user entonces???